# Slick carousel finite, left aligned, NO white space after final slide. Possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

Using slick carousel (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Using a finite, non-centered (so left aligned) slider, when reaching the final slide, I'd like the final slide to cling to the right leaving no white space.

Is this possible?

```
$('.slider').slick({
slidesToScroll: 1,
infinite: false,
variableWidth: true,
dots: true,
speed: 300,
slidesToShow: 1,
centerMode: false
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mr_antlers/jw5a9prf/

Answer (score 0):

The 'placeholder' fix was [removed by owner](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/143).

I found a way to minimise the whitespace. My solution involves detecting if last slider item is visible and then just disabling the 'next' button to prevent further scrolling.

1. **Javascript function to check if element visible**

   ```
   function isVisible($parent, $child) {
   var parentWidth = $parent.outerWidth(),
       parentHeight = $parent.outerHeight(),
       parentPos = $parent.offset(),
       childPos = $child.offset(),
       childWidth = $child.outerWidth(),
       childHeight = $child.outerHeight();

   var isVisibleX = (childPos.left >= parentPos.left && 
           (childPos.left + childWidth) <= (parentPos.left + parentWidth));

   var isVisibleY = (childPos.top >= parentPos.top && 
           (childPos.top + childHeight) <= (parentPos.top + parentHeight))  

   return isVisibleY && isVisibleX;
   }
   ```
2. **Now add a event to your carousel**

   ```
   $carousel.on('afterChange', function(){
       var isVisible = isVisible($('.slider'), $('.slider').find('.slick-slide').last()); 
       if (isVisible) {
           $('.slider').find('.slick-next').hide();
       } else {
           $('.slider').find('.slick-next').show();
       }

   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
float:left;
```

inside class `.slick-track`

Comment: Please explain why this would solve the problem given by T.D. Or explain why the other answer isn't sufficient for solving the problem

Comment: This is not working for me. Actually there is a css property present in slick track `transform: translate3d(259px, 0px, 0px)` due to this `float:left;` is not working.